# Issues after installing Windows 10

Tags: boot, windows-10

I had Windows 8 on my laptop and I installed Windows 10 yesterday.I chose "Keep your files" option during the installation wizard and the installation went successfully.But when it booted up, the screen had reduced resolution (1024x768) and it was working fine until i increased the resolution (1336x768) and it soon showed "LogonUi exception (something like that , it only popped up for a second or so)" and the screen went black. I restarted my laptop and after the boot, it only showed a black screen with a movable cursor and the crtl+shift+del wasnt working as well( it shows that only now). I am thinking of rolling back to prev build. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
Graphics Card : Nvidia GT630M , driver ver 352.86

Comment: uninstall the driver before you perform the upgrade, have the correct driver ready to go, on your desktop and installed before you perform a windows update.